# Hide all images on Visualforce page, minus one

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, images

I'm hiding all images on my page via css, so that an  tag will look better on a pdf and not include the image icons.

My issue is that I would like to render a single logo at the top of the page.  I'm trying to do it by specifying it by id, and by the style tag:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Project__c" 
           extensions="projectToPDFController" 
           renderAs="pdf"
           showHeader="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" 
           standardStylesheets="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css" media="print"> 
            body {
                font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
                } 
            table, th, td{
                 text-align: left;
                 width: 90%;
                 border-collapse: collapse;
                 table-layout: fixed;
                 align: center;
            }
            img{
                display: none;
            }
            #theLogo{
                display: inline;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
    <div align="right">
    <apex:image style="display:inline" id="theLogo" value="/resource/1537340258000/Logo" alt="Logo"/>
    </div>
```

Neither renders the image.  Is there something I'm missing?  Can provide more info if needed.  Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Use a not css selector on the img css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using value="{!$Resource.Logo}" in your apex:image tag instead.

The way you're addressing the image now won't work if you update the image file in the static resource sometime down the road.  It *probably* won't work if you deploy it between environments.  (The long number between "/resource/" and "/Logo" is a timestamp that shows when you last updated the resource's file.)

That issue aside, to understand why referencing the apex:image tag's Id value in your CSS isn't working, take a look at the HTML that's returned when the image is visible. You should see that the image tag's Id is prefixed -- something like this:

```
<img id="j_id0:theLogo" .../>
```

The CSS selector would only apply if it had the same prefix...which is tricky, since that prefix is based on where the image tag appears in the DOM.  It will change if you add elements to your page above the tag!